# Howto pass NSManagedObject via protocol/delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a managed object defined:

```
@objc (Game)
class Game: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var player1: Player
  @NSManaged var player2: Player
  @NSManaged var totalScore: NSNumber
  @NSManaged var gameDate: NSDate
}
```

I initialize it from ViewControllerA, then I give it to ViewControllerB using the delegate pattern. The protocol looks like this:

```
protocol gameProtocol {
    func gameFunction(input: Game)
}
```

ViewControllerB signs up for the protocol:

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController, gameProtocol {...}
```

and implements this function to conform:

```
func gameFunction(input: Game) {
    let currentGame = input
}
```

Then ViewControllerA can send a Game object to VCB as follows:

```
var gameDelegate: gameProtocol!
gameDelegate.gameFunction(myInitializedAndSavedGameObject)
```

This all works, but I need a class level variable inside ViewControllerB so that other code can be written to depend on the game. This, of course, does not work:

```
var currentGame = Game()
func gameFunction(input: Game) {
    currentGame = input
}
```

I don't know the right words for it, but I think I want an initialized, empty Game object. I suppose I could write a convenience init that makes a temporary Game, but that doesn't seem like a good idea.

My current workaround is to have an NSManagedObjectID() and then recreate the object from the ID. But this is a lot of repeated code to get at an object that is central to what this ViewController is designed to work with.

Comment: Why don't you have an instance variable?

Comment: Because I don't know what that is (self-taught hobbyist). But your suggestion led me to discover 'lazy var currentGame = Game()' which seems to be what I want. By making the var lazy, the designated initializer is never incorrectly called. I am certain that the first thing to touch the var will be the gameFunction method, so my other code will compile without crashing the darn thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to push your NSManagedObject to your second View Controller?- You dont need an delegate, you could send your object as instance variable, as Wain already said.

For Example (in your MainViewController)

```
class MainViewControntroller: UIViewController {
    var currentGameObject:YOURNSMANAGEDOBJECT!

    func viewDidLoad() {
        // load your Object
       var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Game")
     .....
     games = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as [YOURNSMANAGEDOBJECT]

    if(games.count > 0) {
        // set to any game object (here is only the last) 
        currentGameObject = games.last?
    }  
   }

}
```

// Initialize your Second View Controller (for example when using segues)

```
if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifierInStoryboard") {

    var yourNextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as yourNextViewControllerClass)
    yourNextViewController.currentGameObject = currentGameObject
```

So you are able to use your NSManagedObject in your SecondViewController - if you want to push it back, you could use a delegate.

Comment: oh I see now. so 'var currentGame: Game!' is an instance variable? Thought I tried that but you're both right. I was missing the !  - however I do need a delegate because my VCs are wrapped up in swipe navigation so they don't directly segue to each other. Didn't want to complicate the question.

Comment: Ok - but its not a problem to pass a variable through a delegate. If you have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: It works now, but I don't know why the instance variable must be terminated with a '!' . Without a ! declaring an instance variable like 'var myVar: myType' throws a compiler error saying that my ViewController class has no designated initializer. Inside standard object definitions this is no problem, it only happens while i'm writing inside a VC class. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

'lazy var currentGame = Game()' seems to be what I want. By making the var lazy, the designated initializer is never incorrectly called. I am certain that the first thing to touch the var will be the gameFunction method, so my other code will compile and it won't crash at runtime. Alternative suggestions welcome.

Comment: 'var currentGame: Game!' is the answer to my question. Thanks guys